# How to differentiate between multiple different connections connecting to a common socket?

Tags: arduino, digital-logic

I'm working on a project that involves 9 female connections on the top of a box, and 4 male connections coming from the front of the box. The requirements of the project involves connecting these male connections to the female connections, however I need to be able to differentiate between these male connections. How do i differentiate between them?

I'm using an arduino as the "brains" of the project. My initial plan was to use 2 4051 multiplexers to extend the number of analog pins on an Arduino Uno to 9, and then use different signal strength on the male connectors to differentiate between them. Through talking to some colleagues, I've also thought of using logic gates.

I'm a novice when it comes to electronics, I apologize in advance if this question is confusing. I've attached an illustration to try to clarify things.

[image: Diagram of project]

Comment: What type of connectors these are? How many pins? You can short the pins in different configurations and then identify by feeding specfic signals from the "female connectors" and reading them.

Comment: Most likely banana plugs. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the second part of your answer, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to put a different signal on each of the male connectors? This could either be a different voltage or else a different frequency using the same voltage for all four, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Connect each of the male connections to an output GPIO pin.  Connect each female to an input GPIO pin.

In a loop, cycle through each of the outputs, turning one on (high) at a time.  While each output is high, check all the inputs to see which, if any, is high.

If you don't have enough GPIO pins (13 total), there are various options.  The easiest is to use a multiplexer on the input pins (reduces 9 inputs to 1 input and 4 outputs).  You can also use a one-hot decoder on the output pins (reduces 4 outputs to 2 outputs).  As a last resort, you can consider an IO expander chip (replaces all 13 pins with a serial bus, such as I2C or SPI).

Comment: Obviously I'm assuming the input GPIO have pull-downs enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that since you didn't suggest the use of the digital I/O pins, you'd like to reserve those for other purposes. Also, since you did suggest the use of your analog input pins, but mentioned you didn't have enough, I'm going to assume you can dedicate up to all 6 of them for this purpose.

I think the easiest thing to think about and do would be to provide four different analog voltages for each of the four male plugs. They would also each have the same output impedance to keep things simpler to analyze, mathematically. You would then wire up your nine female jacks in pairs (9/2=4.5, so you'd need 5 or all 6 of your analog inputs this way), at worst. For example, you might wire things up so that you have 3 analog inputs supporting pairs of jacks (6 total) and 3 analog inputs supporting only one jack (3 total), covering all 9 of your female jacks.

Obviously, in the case of the 3 analog inputs supporting only one jack, it's a simple measurement to make. You measure the voltage and match it up with the voltages assigned to the four male plugs. You can use a simple, high impedance pull-up for the case where no male plug is in the jack. So it is easy to work out if there is a jack in a plug, or not, and if so which one it is.

In the case of the 3 analog inputs supporting pairs of jacks, then you may have 0, 1, or 2 male plugs inserted into female jacks. If you make sure that the Thevenin output resistance of each male plug is the same, then when both female jacks are occupied by male plugs, the voltage you measure will be the average of the voltages for the two plugs. If only one is occupied, then it's as simple as before -- just measure the voltage. If none, then again the high impedance pull-up will tell you that much, as well.

Since you aren't experienced with electronics, I need to explain "Thevenin" and "output impedance" and how to achieve all that in the simplest fashion.

The operating voltage for the Arduino Uno is \$5\:\text{V}\$. You do NOT want to have to create four more voltages for this project. But don't worry. You don't have to. You can easily arrange four new voltages using resistor dividers. So let's look at the schematic for one of the male plugs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp0rHL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Thevenin output impedance (resistance in this case) will be:

$$R_\text{TH}=\frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$

The Thevenin output voltage will be:

$$V_\text{TH}=5\:\text{V}\cdot\frac{ R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$

Since you want all of the male plugs to have the exact same value for \$R_\text{TH}\$, all you have to do is decide what this value should be and make it a design input. There is a sampling period for the Arduino's analog input which probably draws some current for a moment and so I think, just as an educated guess, that you will want \$R_\text{TH}=10\:\text{k}\Omega\$, or less. So let's go with that.

Now, it's just a matter of picking some easy voltages for \$V_{\text{TH}_1}\$, \$V_{\text{TH}_2}\$, \$V_{\text{TH}_3}\$, and \$V_{\text{TH}_4}\$. We probably should stay clear of \$0\:\text{V}\$ and \$5\:\text{V}\$ and use values where all of the possible averages of any pair of them doesn't match up with any single value. Take note that there are six possible pairings, so this means 10 possible voltages or voltage pairings. This suggests you must be able to resolve the separation of \$\frac{5}{10+1}\approx 450\:\text{mV}\$ with your ADC (in the best of cases, though probably you will need to do somewhat better than that.)

I'm going to start out by setting \$V_{\text{TH}_1}=500\:\text{mV}\$ and \$V_{\text{TH}_4}=4.5\:\text{V}\$. You can pick anything, I suppose. But I think those are far enough away from ground or the (+) rail that you should be able to separate them out with your ADC input readings. I'll use a geometric series, in between, with the hopes of avoiding any clashes of the in-between voltages (averages of two male jack voltages or single male jack voltages.)

A geometric sequence looks like \$a\cdot k^i\$, where \$i=0, 1, 2, ...\$. Since we know that \$a\cdot k^0=500\:\text{mV}\$, it follows that \$a=500\:\text{mV}\$. We also know that \$a\cdot k^3=4.5\:\text{V}\$. So we know that \$k=\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{9}\$. This makes \$V_{\text{TH}_2}=1.04\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_{\text{TH}_3}=2.16\:\text{V}\$.

So a table of voltages you need to think about would be:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{\text{TH}_1}&=0.50\:\text{V}\\
\frac{V_{\text{TH}_1}+V_{\text{TH}_2}}{2}&=0.77\:\text{V}\\
V_{\text{TH}_2}&=1.04\:\text{V}\\
\frac{V_{\text{TH}_1}+V_{\text{TH}_3}}{2}&=1.33\:\text{V}\\
\frac{V_{\text{TH}_2}+V_{\text{TH}_3}}{2}&=1.60\:\text{V}\\
V_{\text{TH}_3}&=2.16\:\text{V}\\
\frac{V_{\text{TH}_1}+V_{\text{TH}_4}}{2}&=2.50\:\text{V}\\
\frac{V_{\text{TH}_2}+V_{\text{TH}_4}}{2}&=2.77\:\text{V}\\
\frac{V_{\text{TH}_3}+V_{\text{TH}_4}}{2}&=3.33\:\text{V}\\
V_{\text{TH}_4}&=4.50\:\text{V}\\
\end{align*}$$

That's all 10 voltages (4 male plug voltages plus all 6 paired combinations.)

You should be able to differentiate these, I think. Keep in mind that these exact values will not be read by the ADC perfectly. There will be noise and error. But there is enough distance between them (\$\ge 270\:\text{mV}\$) that you should be okay.

From those voltages, now known, and from the required \$R_\text{TH}=10\:\text{k}\Omega\$, each pair of resistors can be computed now. (Two equations and two unknowns.) The remaining question is how well you can find standard values for the resistors that are close enough to the values you will need and want.

This is where a process similar to "mini-max" methods can be used and where a simple computer program could be used to optimize things, adjusting the geometrically idealized values somewhat while observing how this works out in selecting the eight resistors from standard values. But the problem is also small enough to do by hand trial, too. I'll leave that as an exercise.

But I'll toss out a first cut using 2% resistor values. Probe 1 might use \$R_1=100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2=11\:\text{k}\Omega\$; probe 2 might use \$R_1=46.4\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2=12.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$; probe 3 might use \$R_1=22.6\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2=17.8\:\text{k}\Omega\$; and probe 4 might use \$R_1=11\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2=100\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Keep in mind that with 2% resistor values that the errors may be perhaps as much as \$\pm 50\:\text{mV}\$ around the ideal values, for that reason alone. Luckily, I think there is enough margin here to make that work out. But you need to be aware. You may want to go with 1% for that reason, if you can readily get them. (They allow closer to ideal values, too, because there are more selection options with 1% resistors.)

The only thing I'd add at this point is that the impedance will drop to \$5\:\text{k}\Omega\$ when pairs of plugs are involved. But this will not be a problem for the ADC. Less is better.

Oh, and you will need some kind of pull-up resistor for each female jack so that you can read \$5\:\text{V}\$ readily when there is no male jack in place at the analog input. This should be perhaps \$1\:\text{M}\Omega\$. The ADC input is specified as \$100\:\text{M}\Omega\$ (when it isn't sampling, anyway.) But you might consider something as little as \$470\:\text{k}\Omega\$. The error wouldn't be that much with the male jacks inserted.